# How to get user location continuously even your app is killed

Tags: android

What is the best way to get user location after each two minute even you app is killed

Comment: create one background services and that service work in background itself. continuously get location..

Comment: but when service is stop then who i can get location update

Comment: Yes you can achieve this by putting some effort and R&D.

Comment: i have don a lot r$d but fail that's why i have asked

Comment: You should use a Service for that, you cant do nothing if the user stops your service.

Comment: Very easy to find out how to do this with a bit of googling

Comment: @NisarAhmad you will find easily on Stack overflow or googling.

Comment: @Aks4125 i have tried a lot but not the condition is avoid to use alarm manager

Comment: Try this link its best example [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) if u cant understand let me know

Comment: @NisarAhmad [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726670/continuous-location-updates-in-background) [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978060/android-continuous-location-update) as well as @viveka's answer  hint- use `AlarmManager` to achieve interval updates.

Comment: Add a service and add a broadcast receiver for boot complete. So that service will run after restart also

Answer (score 1):

**Background Service Example Android**

Use a Android Service to run code in the background even when the app is killed. Use a BroadcasteReceiver to restart the service when app is killed by user and Android JobService to run your location gathering code at specified intervals.

**Try This its working for me getting the location when app is in killed state**

**[Android-Background-Services-Exmaple](https://github.com/surenderkhowal/Android-Background-Services-Exmaple)**

https://github.com/surenderkhowal/Android-Background-Services-Exmaple

Comment: thanks this example also show that how to start service when device reboots. This example working in android 13 i have testing.

Comment: NOTE: - In order to start service when device reboots in Chinese like oppo,vivo,mi,OnePlus,redmi,etc you have to give auto start permission with that permission you wont be able to start service when device reboots.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use a [Background Service](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) for your activity.

Within this service, you set your service to poll for your location at the interval you wish.

After which, you can use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to broadcast the result of your interest to return the useful results to your application.

Comment: but when app is killed or device reboot then service stops please tell me another way

Comment: You can add a broadcast receiver for getting the boot complete

Comment: @NisarAhmad http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: @Ameer Good suggestion, this will ensure that you can start your service once the phone restarts

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Started service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to run code in the background even when the app is killed.
Use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [Timer task](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) to run your location gathering code at specified intervals.

Timer example

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {}
        }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: can you send me sample please

Comment: You can find samples at the links provided and try searching for answers to specific problems you encounter while trying to implement this yourself.

Comment: I have added an example for the Timer. How to use the different types of services is in the started service link. I hope this answers your original question

Comment: I tried this code, will not run when the screen is off.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what J Whitfield and sihao have suggested, You can also make your service as a Start service (not an Intent Service). Then on the onStartCommand of service, return START_STICKY.

You can also try to run your service in separate process so it won't be killed even if your app is killed.