# I cannot able to stop the service and BroadcastReceiver.I have tried the below code

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Actually I want to update my location for every minute to the server, I have looked into so many links but none of them working fine for me.Finally I got this link

I have tried this link: 
        https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/service-in-android/
        for getting the location in a service.I am using the sourcecode from the link but I cannot able to stop the service and BroadcastReceiver

I am starting the Service and BroadcastReceiver like following code

```
    //Starting Service
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleService.class);
                    startService(intent);

    //Starting BroadcastReceiver
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(GoogleService.str_receiver));
```

I have tried the below code to stop service and BroadcastReceiver.

```
//Unregistering BroadcastReceiver
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ServiceLocActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

//stopping service
 Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleService.class);
 stopService(it);
```

The above code is not working.
 I cannot able to stop Service and Broadcast Receiver
 Can you please help me on this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What error you got in logcat..

Comment: @SardarKhan, please check the logcat            09-28 10:49:33.785 883-970/? D/PerfServiceManager: [PerfService] MESSAGE_TIMEOUT:103 
? I/libPerfService: 3: set: 3
? I/libPerfService: 3: set freq: 819000
? I/libPerfService: 3: set vcore level: 0
? I/PerfService: PerfServiceNative_getPackName
? I/libPerfService: perfGetLastBoostPid 5392
? D/PerfServiceManager: [PerfService] getLastBoostPid 5392 
? I/libPerfService: perfGetLastBoostPid 5392

Comment: can you show the code where error occurs.?

Comment: Or you can show the full logcat error report its not clear from this that you getting which error.

Comment: Whether the service is bound to activity or not show the activity code here.

Answer (score 2):

As intent service automatically stops after completing its cycle. Put your latest lat and lon in global variable.

```
public class LocationService extends IntentService{
public Config sharedData;
public boolean logincase = true;
ExceptionSave ex;
Intent broadcastIntent;
public String journeyState="jr_init";
public static boolean performTasks = true;
private static final String TAG = "com.live.locationservices.LocationServic";

public LocationService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (this.performTasks) {
//If this variable is true just call your endpoint and send global variable lat and lon to server.

}
}
public class ResponseReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.live.ResponseReceiver.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if(LocationServiceDriver.performTasks){
//Start your service again 1 mint post dealy
}
}
```

Unregistered your broadcast receiver on activity destroy.When you done your task just set LocationServiceDriver.performTasks=false

Comment: Hi OmarHayat, Thanks for your reply.Actually I want to update my location to the server for every 1 minute and I want to unregister broadcast register when a button click.I want to update my location for evey 1 minute even when the application foreground, background, closed. I want to unregister broadcast register when a button click

Comment: okey then use foreground service which update your location and in that service use post dealy of 1 mint and do your update after 1 mint delay.You can unregistered your receiver on button click like this if(receiver!=null) {
                this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            }

Comment: Foreground service never stop even os can't stop that service.

Comment: Thanks OmarHayat, what about when application is Closed ?I have to send the location even when application is closed also.    How to stop service in the existing code which I am using ?

Comment: Please check this tutorial it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473546/android-how-to-get-user-location-continuously-even-your-app-is-killed

Comment: You can use LocationListener interface implement this interface in your service and use its method to get updated location

Comment: The link which I am using having almost the same code but I am unable to stop the service and unregister receiver.

Comment: stopService(new Intent(this,YourServiceName.class)); stop like this

Comment: Please put try catch send exception you get while stooping your service

Comment: @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSelf();
    } put this in your service as well

Comment: I have added onDestroy() method but it didn't worked

Comment: please send exception while stooping your service

Comment: ? I/BufferQueueProducer: [eg.com.servicelocation.ServiceLocActivity](this:0xb7557428,id:1494,api:1,p:22551,c:231) queueBuffer: fps=3.94 dur=1014.60 max=961.67 min=15.64
09-28 12:07:12.918 231-231/? I/SurfaceFlinger: [Built-in Screen (type:0)] fps:3.975461,dur:1006.17,max:952.41,min:16.78
09-28 12:07:12.998 883-970/? D/PerfServiceManager: [PerfService] MESSAGE_TIMEOUT:103

Comment: Unregistered receiver first then remove location callback then stop service

Comment: How to remove Location Callback ?I am new to Android can you please help me.

Comment: locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

Comment: I have to call this from activity.Im confused how to call this, I have to pass LocationListener Object

Comment: Create static method in your service and call that from activity to removeUpdates

Comment: Using your serviceName.yourmethod();

Comment: This is method I not try yet but may work put method in service                                              public static void stopService(){
        stopSelf();
    } and call like this from activity may it work                                                                                                                         
    yourServiceName.stopService();

Comment: hey Sorry for delay I have some other work.In the same static method I have to call both  
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);  and stopSelf();   WIll this work ?  locationlistener object showing error cannot resolve symbol

Comment: public static void stopService(){ stopSelf(); } yourServiceName.stopService();  use this only don't try to remove location updates and check if works then okey else send me your code

Comment: stopSelf() is not taking as static inside static method in service