# onLocationChanged doesn't work while recording

Tags: java, android, gps, location

Is there any way I can let GPS update every few seconds while using Record?
I heard some articles say it needs to work in the foreground but I don't know how.
I want it works in the background and record simultaneously.

```
  private void getLocal() {
    /**沒有權限則返回*/
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    String localProvider = "";
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    /**知道位置後..*/
    Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(localProvider);
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener);
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener);
    if (location != null){
        longitude=location.getLongitude();
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        Log.d("location", longitude.toString()+","+latitude.toString());
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocal: ");
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener);
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener);
    }
}
/**監聽位置變化*/
LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude=location.getLongitude();
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        Log.d("location", longitude.toString()+","+latitude.toString());
    }
};
```

Comment: _"I heard some articles say it needs to work in the foreground but I don't know how. "_ The concept is [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). Only the notification of the app needs to be "visible" (in the notification panel), not the whole UI.

Comment: Thanks, But I wonder how I can track my GPS every second when I am recording. What method should I use?

Comment: You should use `requestLocationUpdates()` as you already do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manage the `LocationManager` (including `requestLocationUpdates()`) into the Application Class;
Then you should use a Foreground Service (specifying `android:foregroundServiceType="location"`) that implements a `WAKE_LOCK` to keep your Application working in background.

You can read how to implement a foreground service here: [Continuously get user location when app is paused or killed in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71377805/continuously-get-user-location-when-app-is-paused-or-killed-in-android/71435391#71435391)

As alternative [here](https://github.com/BasicAirData/GPSLogger) you can browse a real working example on a free and opensource GPS Logging app.